# Restrict to category group in Solspace Super Search?

Tags: supersearch

Is there a way to restrict search to a group or groups of categories when using the {exp:super_search:results} tag? I see only category and category_indicator. I have an issue where the same category name/url indicator exists in two groups, but I only want to search for entries that are in one of the category groups and not the other.